# android sqlite query no return?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an sqlite database and I want to query through the db and populate a listview with the return, but the listview shows only one row which much return more than one row and there is also no error. Item is a class which contains the setters and getters.

I use this method for the query:

```
fillList2(edtSeach.getQuery().toString().toLowerCase(),"zankodict", "id","eng",Long.valueOf(1),Long.valueOf(1794));
```

which is this method:

```
 private void fillList2(String keyword,String table, String columnn,String column2,Long num1,Long num2) {
        if (keyword.equals(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)) {
            this.myList = new ArrayList();
        } else if (keyword.toCharArray().length < 2) {
            myList.clear();
            myList.add(DBQuery.a(keyword,table,columnn,column2,num1,num2));

        } else {
            myList.clear();
            myList.add(DBQuery.a(keyword,table,columnn,column2,num1,num2));
        }
                myListView.setAdapter(new AdapterEN(getActivity(), R.layout.single_row, myList,keyword));
        }
    }
```

DBQUery.class

```
import android.database.Cursor;


public class DBQuery {
    private static Item itemm, itemm2;
    private static Cursor cursor10;
    public static Item a(String keyword,String table, String columnn,String column2, Long num1,Long num2) {
        C0101f.getDatabaseHelper().openDatabase();
         cursor10 =  C0101f.getDatabaseHelper().QueryData("select * from "+ table +" WHERE "+ columnn +" between "+num1+" and "+num2+ " And " +column2+ " LIKE '"+ keyword + "%'");
        itemm2 = cur(table);
        C0101f.getDatabaseHelper().closeDataBase();
        return itemm2;
    }
    public static Item cur(String table){
        switch (table) {
            case "zankodict":
                if (cursor10 != null) {
                    if (cursor10.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            itemm = new Item();
                            itemm.setId(cursor10.getString(0));
                            itemm.setEng(cursor10.getString(1));
                        } while (cursor10.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "kudict":
                if (cursor10 != null) {
                    if (cursor10.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            itemm = new Item();
                            itemm.setId(cursor10.getString(0));
                            itemm.setKurd(cursor10.getString(1));
                            itemm.setId2(cursor10.getLong(2));
                        } while (cursor10.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "ardict":
                if (cursor10 != null) {
                    if (cursor10.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            itemm = new Item();
                            itemm.setId(cursor10.getString(0));
                            itemm.setAr(cursor10.getString(1));
                            itemm.setId2(cursor10.getLong(2));
                        } while (cursor10.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return itemm;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don´t know what `Item` is, but you set every cursor query a new one with `item = new Item()` . And I can´t see where you add this new item anywhere, so I guess it´s allways overriden and the result is just one item.

Comment: DBQuery just returns allways one item. And I can´t see a method where you are looping and add a new item on every loop....

Comment: Item is a class which contains getters and setters, is there a problem?

Comment: no, no problem, but your code is a little bit confusing for a non participant. But I guess, you are adding only one item, because there is nowhere a loop where you add more items to `myList`...I guess the method `fillList` clears the list....

Comment: thnx, understood, I will add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added an array list which adds the Items to it every time we go through the loop.

```
import android.database.Cursor;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by RRR on 11/12/2016.
 */

public class DBQuery {
    public static ArrayList<Item> myList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    public static ArrayList<Item> myList2 = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private static Item itemm;
    private static Cursor cursor10;
    public static ArrayList<Item> a(String keyword,String table, String columnn,String column2, Long num1,Long num2) {
        C0101f.getDatabaseHelper().openDatabase();
         cursor10 =  C0101f.getDatabaseHelper().QueryData("select * from "+ table +" WHERE "+ columnn +" between "+num1+" and "+num2+ " And " +column2+ " LIKE '"+ keyword + "%'");
        myList2 = cur(table);
        C0101f.getDatabaseHelper().closeDataBase();
        return myList2;
    }
    public static ArrayList<Item> cur(String table){
        switch (table) {
            case "zankodict":
                if (cursor10 != null) {
                    if (cursor10.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            itemm = new Item();
                            itemm.setId(cursor10.getString(0));
                            itemm.setEng(cursor10.getString(1));
                            myList.add(itemm);
                        } while (cursor10.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "kudict":
                if (cursor10 != null) {
                    if (cursor10.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            itemm = new Item();
                            itemm.setId(cursor10.getString(0));
                            itemm.setKurd(cursor10.getString(1));
                            itemm.setId2(cursor10.getLong(2));
                            myList.add(itemm);
                        } while (cursor10.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "ardict":
                if (cursor10 != null) {
                    if (cursor10.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            itemm = new Item();
                            itemm.setId(cursor10.getString(0));
                            itemm.setAr(cursor10.getString(1));
                            itemm.setId2(cursor10.getLong(2));
                            myList.add(itemm);
                        } while (cursor10.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return myList;
    }

}
```